# Is making a call to the API in the componentWillReceiveProps on router parameter change is correct or not?

Tags: reactjs, redux, components, react-router-v4, dynamic-routing

I have set of components where each component has different data being served by the server. So, when the user clicks on component 4, there should be an API call and get the information about the clicked Link.
[image]

For an initial update of child components, I'm calling an action in `componentWillMount` and Since the route parameter is the only source for me to detect which link is been clicked by the user.I'm calling the API in the `componentWillReceiveProps` based on the changed `page_id` in the url.But in the official document of reactjs, it is mentioned as `ComponentDidMount` is the right place to make the async call.

I've gone through many blogs and tutorials regarding this.Unfortunately, i couldn't find the best solution.Please guide me on this.Here is my parent Component

```
  import React from 'react';
  import {CommentBox} from './CommentBox';
  import SuggestionBox from './SuggestionBox';
  import ProductBlog from './ProductBlog';
  import FeaturesList from './FeaturesList';
  import ContactForm from './ContactForm';
  import WebVRSuggestion from './WebVRSuggestion';
  import ModelFooter from './ModelFooter';
  import WebVR from './WebVR';
  import {connect} from 'react-redux';
  import {getProductInfo,getSuggestions} from '../actions/productActions';
  import {getComments} from '../actions/commentActions';

  class SmartProduct extends React.Component{

  //To execute the parent before the child componentWillMount(){}
  componentWillMount(){
    // if(this.props.productInfo === undefined || this.props.productInfo.length == 0){
    this.props.getProductInfo(this.props.page,this.props.pageId);
    this.props.getComments(this.props.page,this.props.pageId);
    this.props.getSuggestions(this.props.page,this.props.pageId);
  // }
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
     if(nextProps.page !== this.props.page || nextProps.pageId !== this.props.pageId){
         this.props.getProductInfo(nextProps.page,nextProps.pageId);
         this.props.getComments(nextProps.page,nextProps.pageId);
         this.props.getSuggestions(nextProps.page,nextProps.pageId);
       }
  }

  render(){
      return (
        <div className="container-fluid bg-darkGrey ">
          <div className="row mx-0 py-3 bgTheme">
            {/* <h3>{this.props.page}</h3>
            <h3>{this.props.pageId}</h3>*/}
            <div className="col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3 mb-2">
              <CommentBox page={this.props.page}
              pageId={this.props.pageId}
              comments={this.props.comments}
               />
            </div>
            <div className="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6 productWrapper">
              <div className="productVR rounded" >
              <WebVR width={625} height={405} />
               {/* <WebVR /> <div id="container123"></div>
                <div id="container123" style={containerStyle}></div>
               */}
              </div>
              <ModelFooter page={this.props.page}
                pageId={this.props.pageId}
                productInfo={this.props.productInfo}
               />
            </div>
            <div className="col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3 ">
              <SuggestionBox
              page={this.props.page}
              pageId={this.props.pageId}
              suggestions={this.props.suggestions}
              />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="row mx-0">
            <div className="col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
               <ProductBlog page={this.props.page}
               pageId={this.props.pageId}
                 productInfo={this.props.productInfo}
                />
            </div>
            <div className="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6 productFeatures rounded">
                <FeaturesList page={this.props.page}
                pageId={this.props.pageId}
                productInfo={this.props.productInfo}
                />
            </div>
            <div className="col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3 rounded">
              <ContactForm page={this.props.page} pageId={this.props.pageId} />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="row mx-0 mt-4 mb-2">
            <div className="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 bg-info py-2 rounded text-center">
              <h5 className="text-white mb-0">You Might Also Like These</h5>
            </div>
          </div>
          <WebVRSuggestion
          page={this.props.page}
          pageId={this.props.pageId}
          suggestions={this.props.suggestions}
          />
        </div>
      );
    }
  }

  function mapStateToProps(state){
    const {isLoading}=state.productloader
    return {
      productInfo:state.products.productsInfo,
      comments:state.comments.comments,
      suggestions:state.products.suggestions

    }
  }

  export default connect(mapStateToProps,{getProductInfo,getComments,getSuggestions})(SmartProduct);
```

Comment: I'm not clear on what you're asking? Do you have a specific question or concern with what you're implementing?

Comment: is calling the API  in `componentWillReceiveProps` on router parameter change is correct or not.If, not what is the right approach??

Comment: Gotcha, I'll type out an answer here in a minute.

Comment: Thanks, i'll be waiting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks to be an acceptable practice. Be aware that you can sometimes get unexpected results with componentWillReceiveProps on the initial render, but other than that this looks fine.

However, if you really want your code to be more deterministic, you could create higher-level components for each route you need and call your async data functions in the `componentDidMount`. That way you can more easily cache your data between routes.

*Edit:
After taking a closer look at your code the higher-level component may not work for your case since I'm guessing you'll have an indeterminable number of products that could be rendered by this same component. `ComponentDidMount` is the preferred method for async calls because it's called exactly once, whereas `componentWillReceiveProps` is called quite frequently, and if you're not careful you could end up sending a lot of unnecessary async requests. It looks like you're only calling your async functions when the route changes though so you shouldn't have this issue.

Comment: Ok,cool.Could you please tell me how exactly the higher level components should be.So that I can accept this as an answer.Thanks @Chris

Comment: No problem, I just edited my answer with some more explanation. Hope it helps!